# Getting snapshots of tasks running behind in android programmatically

Tags: android

I would like to know how can i get snapshots of activities running in background like the one we have in latest task managers . Any input on this is highly helpful .

Answer (score 0):

The method you want is `getRunningTasks` from the `ActivityManager` class.

Read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29).

From the above link:

```
public List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> getRunningTasks(int maxNum)

Return a list of the tasks that are currently running, with the most
recent being first and older ones after in order
```

Comment: I want the image of the activity like you get when home button is long pressed in ICS..(Similar to task manager of ICS)